# How to insert ck Editor word count into MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, ckeditor

Does anyone know if there is a way to insert the word count from ck Editor into a MYSQL database?

I can't find any information about it.

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
$id = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
}
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *  FROM beoordelingen WHERE beoordelingen.beoordelingid='$id'  AND beoordelingen.deletedbyadmin=0");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($sql)){
if ($row["inlijn"] == '') {
    echo"";
    }else{
        echo"
        <form action='beoordelinbewerkck.php' name='alleenlees' id='alleenlees'>
        <textarea name='inlijn' cols='61' rows='40' id='inlijn'> " . $row['inlijn'] . "</textarea>
        <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'inlijn',{
            uiColor: '#f4eb8c',height: 800
            });
            </script>
            </form>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>";
            }
            }
            }
?>
```

Comment: I would look into [optimizing your SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html) in your query. You are using `SELECT *` which is generally bad practice as you are often selecting more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for ckEditor that will display the word count. You can find it in the ckEditor site or at [this link](http://w8tcha.github.io/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin/).

What you have to do then is to add the value of the counter to the data you submit to the database. To do this, if you are using a replacement for a textarea, you can use an hidden field in the form. Or pass it in the array of data for the Ajax request to update the textarea.
You haven't post code so I can only make a guess.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the code. Could you explain to me how to use the hidden field. For say if the row for wordcount is called 'words'?

Comment: You should download and add the plugin to the ckEditor instance to make it work... :)